# PHP simpleXML - foreach loop run

Tags: php, xml

Actually I'm stuck on running a foreach loop through a simple xml document. The document looks like this:

```
<outfits>
    <outfit default="1" skin="0xFCDBBA" species="stud">
        <head url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/heads/01/head1" c="0xF2B38A" c2="0xffffff" z="33000"/>
        <face url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/faces/01/stud3" c="0x996633" c2="0xffffff" z="34000"/>
        <midsection url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/midsections/01/ms1" z="9000"/>
        <leg url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/legs/01/legs1" z="10000"/>
        <hair url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/hair/01/hr11" c="0x5C1C01" c2="0xffffff" z="37000"/>
    </outfit>
</outfits>
```

So I kinda try to have each node as a single item.

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($outfitUrl);

foreach($xml->outfit->children() as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Sadly nothing would show up.

Comment: Do `echo $item->asXML();`.

Comment: Can't echo, use `print_r($item)`, you can see the attributes, then you can use `->attributes()`.

Comment: sadly, indeed. also sadly you didn't share what you're missing in the output and why you expected it there.

Answer (score 0):

**The output of your code is as expected, because the nodes are empty**
(though they have data stored inside attributes):

```
<leg url="http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/stud/legs/01/legs1" z="10000"/>
```

If it had a value, it would look like this, and it would be echoed by your code:

```
<leg url="http://someurl" z="10000">This is a node value.</leg>
```

**If you want to retrieve the attributes of those nodes, you need a second `foreach`-loop:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->outfit->children() as $item) {

    // this loop will display all attributes of the current node:
    foreach ($item->attributes() as $att => $attvalue)
        echo "$att: $attvalue" . PHP_EOL;

}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/312473

**If you know the names of the attributes you want, you can access them directly:**

```
foreach ($xml->outfit->children() as $item) {

    echo $item['url'] . PHP_EOL;

}
```

**If you even know the nodes' names you want, you can go...**

```
foreach ($xml->outfit as $outfit) {

    echo $outfit['species'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo $outfit->hair['url'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo $outfit->face['url'] . PHP_EPÖ;
    // etc.

}
```

see the PHP manual for hints: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php